# How to change referencing style of revtex4-1 in ShareLatex

Tags: citing, harvard-style

## ShareLatex

I am using ShareLatex, I really like one of the templates available there but I do not want the same referencing style. I would like to use Harvard referencing style instead. I did some search and discovered how to do Harvard citation but it is not working on this particular [template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/aps).

If you use the [template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/aps), I changed the original code to the following

```
\documentclass[reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


% 's for citation
\newcommand\posscite[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s (\citeyear{#1})}
\newcommand\citee[1]{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}



% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=cyan,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor = blue,
}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
%\usepackage{hyperref}% add hypertext capabilities
%\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
%\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines

%\usepackage[showframe,%Uncomment any one of the following lines to test 
%%scale=0.7, marginratio={1:1, 2:3}, ignoreall,% default settings
%%text={7in,10in},centering,
%%margin=1.5in,
%%total={6.5in,8.75in}, top=1.2in, left=0.9in, includefoot,
%%height=10in,a5paper,hmargin={3cm,0.8in},
%]{geometry}

\begin{document}

%\preprint{APS/123-QED}

\title{Some Title}% Force line breaks with \\
\thanks{A footnote to the article title}%

\author{some Author}
\affiliation{University of York, Management School}


\author{Some author}
 \homepage{http://www.Second.institution.edu/~Charlie.Author}
\affiliation{Heriot-Watt University, School of Mathematical and Computer Sciences}


\author{Another Author}
\affiliation{University of Exeter, Business School}


\date{\today}% It is always \today, today,
             %  but any date may be explicitly specified

\begin{abstract}
    fdfada 
\end{abstract}

\pacs{Valid PACS appear here}% PACS, the Physics and Astronomy
                             % Classification Scheme.
%\keywords{Suggested keywords}%Use showkeys class option if keyword
                              %display desired
\maketitle

%\tableofcontents

\section{\label{sec:level1}Introduction}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Motivation- What is the problem
    \item Short literature review (solution proposed in the literature so far) such as subsampling, m out of n bootstrap and wild bootstrap and PB
    \item Shortcomings of all existing bootstraps
    \item Main idea (paraphrased see Adriana PB)
\end{itemize}


\section{\label{sec:level2}Main Result}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Model
    \item Hypothesis of interest
    \item CI of interest LIKE WB
    \item Descriptive steps of the TWB
    \item Theorem A (bootstrap validity) proof in appendix
\end{itemize}


\bibliography{mybibliography.bib}

\end{document}
```

Can someone help me when I write `\cite{A}` to give me the Harvard referencing style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to thank LianTze Lim so much for helping me with this:

> Hello,
>
> Yes, you can add these in your preamble:
>
> ```
> \setcitestyle{authoryear,round}
> \bibliographystyle{dcu}
> ```
>
> and remember to use `\citep` for parenthetical citations (John, 1991)
> and `\citet` for text citations John (1991).

Comment: Is there a way to use parenthetical citations by default (with `\cite`)?